# Returning null Value for User from Model

Tags: laravel, model, routes, laravel-5.4

I'm getting a null value for the user at `http://localhost:8000/messages`. I am trying to get the user table values within the Message model. It also gives a null value in the console.

**Route**

```
Route::get('/messages', function () {
    return App\Message::with('user')-> get();
})-> middleware('auth');
```

**Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Message extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['message'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

**User** Model code:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function messages()
    {
         return $this-> hasMany(Message::class);
    }
}
```

**Snapshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`messages` table must have `user_id` with proper user ID to make `belongsTo` relationship work.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse